# Bounded matrix, matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Assume $A \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n, \text{Mat}_N(\mathbb{R}))$, s.t. there exists a $C$, s.t.

$$\Vert A (x)\Vert \leq C,  \  \  \text{ for all }x.$$

Can we say now that $\vert x^T A x  \vert = \Vert x^T \Vert \Vert Ax \Vert \leq C \Vert x \Vert^2 $?

I think it can't be right, because there are different norm one could use as matrix norms.

Comment: using different matrix norms just means that you will be using different vector norms. The relation will hold if you use consistent vector/matrix norms.

Comment: Ok, thank you! so using the operator norm and usual norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ works here?

Comment: the operator norm uses in its definition a vector norm. If you want to use the "usual" euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, your operator norm will be the spectral norm (uses eigenvalues).